# Winforms: TreeView focus stolen by TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, treeview

**Having following scenario:**

- `TabControl` with two pages on the `Form`
- Each tab page contains `TreeView` component
- Tab page `Enter` event:

  - Populates the `TreeView` with generated nodes
  - Selects desired node to be highlighted (`tree.SelectedNode = desiredNode`)
  - Activates the `TreeView` to receive focus and thus show the selected node in different colour (`tree.Select()`)
- There is one little difference between the two tabs:

  - Additionaly to the `TreeView` (and buttons), there is also `TextBox` control placed on the second one.

**Problem:**
The page with the `TextBox` sets the focus to such `TextBox` and there seems to be no way to focus the `TreeView`. Used methods (and their combinations):

- `tree.Select()`
- `tree.Focus()`
- `form.ActiveControl = tree`

Clicking on the `TreeView`'s free area (avoid clicking any node) does the job and the selected node is highlighted. The same situation with pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> cycling the controls in tab order until `TreeView` is reached.

**Question:**
Is there a way to focus the `TreeView` and not to let the TextBox steal the focus after a tab is `Enter`ed?

Comment: You forgot to check `TabIndex`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like Sinatr said you could use the TabIndex on the tab with the textbox to set to proper order of the controls.

Comment: Hmmm, haven't understand it, but tried and the observation (you probably wanted to share) is following:

The control having the minimal TabOrder is activated after Enter event. The problem is, the TextBox should have lower TabOrder because it's above the TreeView :o( Did I miss anything else?

Comment: The Order of the controls in one tab or windows form is set by the order of their placement. May be you put the TreeView first and then add the Textbox to the screen. There is an icon in Visual Studio for the TabOrder can you look in there?

Comment: Yes, this is clear now: the TreeView must have the lowest TabIndex. It does not matter if it is set manually or via the Tab Order button "Wizard".

The problem is, if the desired tab order is different than the one required for the ability to focus the TreeView (which is my case now). I would prefer to have option to Focus the TreeView regardless of its TabIndex...

Anyway, thank you for hints.